# How to determine the IP of the computer that connects to me?

Tags: linux, macos, unix, networking

Here's the scenario:
in a private network, there are only two computers connected to this private network.
Say, I am using computer A. Computer B will then connects to me and is looking at my shared folders.
If I am using computer A, how will I know the IP address of the one connecting at me? (in this case, computer B?)

please consider the two computers to be unix-based (may it be Mac OS or linux).
What will be the unix command for that? `ifconfig` can only show me my IP. How about the list of IPs that are connecting at me?

(additional note: I have seen this possible in my friends laptop. He's using Conky. And from there, he can determine how many are connected to that laptop. However, it only shows the number of connects, and not the actual IP.)

please help.

Comment: i see that -p needs a protocol, may i know what protocol to use here? TCP?

Comment: That -p is for the program, not the protocol, see link in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use [netstat](http://linux.die.net/man/8/netstat)

```
netstat -l -n
```

You can even see "live" information by using the `-c` option. The `-p` option can be used to determine the program that actually owns the socket.