# Programmatically find IP of devices directly connected over ethernet

Tags: macos, networking

I'm using a Macbook to interface with an ARM development board (Beagleboard xM) over SSH and I use a direct Ethernet connection from the board to my mac.  I know I can connect to the board just fine if I know the IP.  *Usually* it will take the next address in line from the last time I connected (e.g. 192.168.2.x -> 192.168.2.x+1), however, sometimes it does not.  To find the device on my network I've tried using nmap -sP and -PN, both will return with only the IP of, what I think is, the virtual router on my mac.  I have also tried the usual ping 192.168.2.255, this will either return no devices connected or, as mentioned previously, the virtual router.

Does anyone know why it does this or if there is a way for a mac to list all the IPs it is directly connected to over Ethernet (no router, computer to computer)?  If I need to I also run Ubuntu 13.04 on my Macbook, so that is an option.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated, randomly guessing in the dark at the IP is driving me crazy and scripts I've attempted to make have had no avail.
Thanks!

Comment: Is there a good reason why you don't just use a static address?

Comment: I tried using one, however my Mac refuses to share the internet unless the client is using DHCP.

Answer (score 1):

If you install the avahi daemon on the Beagleboard you should be able to see it between the other Zeroconf devices, thus allowing you to connect to with the name `hostname.local`, where hostname is the host name of the board.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, when I run "$ ssh -X root@alarm.local" I only get the error "ssh: Could not resolve hostname alarm.local: nodename nor servname provided, or not known".  I verified I have Avahi packages installed (and reinstalled) and when I run "hostname" on the beagleboard it returns "alarm".  I apologize if I'm forgetting something obvious, I'm horrible when it comes to networking.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, I used the app WaterRoof to figure out what IPs were connected and look for something like what I thought it should be. You may see lots of stuff from places you did not know were connecting to your computer, but I was able to at least narrow it way down and try the few IPs that looked possible, and I got it going. You may try disconnecting/reconnecting the ethernet so it has to renegotiate a connection, and from that you should see it in WaterRoof.

Or maybe this give it to you:

[How to determine the IP of the computer that connects to me?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6868079/how-to-determine-the-ip-of-the-computer-that-connects-to-me?rq=1)